# training section of dqn and comparison with SVR and RF

Tags: testing, deep-learning, training-data, reinforcement-learning, unsupervised-learning

I have some problem in understanding training section of **DQN**.
Where is **Xtrain** and **Ytrain** in **DQN**? Because it is not clear in DQN algorithm.

```
https://cdn-images-1.medium.com/max/1600/1*nb61CxDTTAWR1EJnbCl1cA.png
```

Also, if I need to compare my results of  **dqn** versus results of **random forest** and **support vector regression** . I need to have Xtrain and Ytrain for them.

**(What I mean by replacement is that to replace the deep learning section with a supervised learning or unsupervised learning approach?)**

Answer (score 0):

DQN is a reinforcement learning algorithm, there is no X_train or Y_train directly because the training data is the experience tuples obtained by interacting with the environment (the emulator). In the image you included, you can think the Q values as the targets (the y), and the sequence s and preprocessed sequence phi as the inputs. (the x).

You cannot really compare DQN to a RF or an SVR because DQN is Reinforcemente Learning, while RF/SVR are Supervised Learning algorithms, they don't solve the same problem, so cannot compare.

Comment: Thanks Matias, why their problems are different?Is it because of definition of train and test in supervised learning and RL?

Comment: No, because the RL problem and supervised learning are formulated in a completely different way. I would say if you don't know this difference, you should learnn this before delving into Reinforcement Learning.

Comment: I think I will now insist on you studying the sub-fields of Machine Learning, namely Supervised, Unsupervised, and Reinforcement Learning. These deal with three separate and completely different problems, so asking for comparison is effectively meaningless.

Comment: Matis, what about your idea? (What I mean by replacement is that to replace the deep learning section with a supervised learning or unsupervised learning approach?)

Comment: 1- what are benefits that is brings with deep-Q-learning instead of running Q-learning?

Is the following reason correct? It approximate the amount of Q instead of have an exact amount of Q and its benefits is that we can use it when we do not have the all of the Q-table?In Deep Reinforcement learning for instance in Deep Q-learning we can not calculate the exact Q-table ( it is more usable when we are not able to find the complete Q-table because of huge working space)! and this is what is benefits of DQN in comparison with Q learning approach !

Comment: Approximation of Q with few range of states instead of having complete Q-table!

2- Also, is it possible to replace deep learning structure of DQN with a (un)supervised approach?

Comment: Comments are not to ask new questions.